# Saving the Antd DatePicker value to the DB by a key

Tags: reactjs, callback, datepicker, antd

Antd DatePicker documentation has code examples for onOk, onChange callbacks, and those callbacks essentially just print the value that had been selected by the user.
What if in the callback i need to pass some other information besides the *value*, how can this be achieved?

to be specific, i have a Table, with DatePicker element on every row, like in the screen below
[Table with DatePicker on every row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ecrk.png)

each row has a key which corresponds to the database primary key.
When user presses OK in the DatePicker, the modified date has to be saved in the db, and thus i need to know the parameters of the DatePicker element, e.g. the key could be stored in className.
How can the pk be passed to the callback?

For the editable cells, the whole row is available in the handleSave callback:

```
const columnsProcessed = columns.map((col) => {
      if (!col.editable)
      {
         return col;
      }
      return {
         ...col,
         onCell: (record) => ({
            record,
            editable: col.editable,
            dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
            title: col.title,
            handleSave,
         }),
      };
   });

const handleSave = (row) => {
   const newData = [...reqdata];   //reqdata is from useState
   const index = newData.findIndex((item) => row.key === item.key);
   const item = newData[index];
   newData.splice(index, 1, {
      ...item,
      ...row,
   });

   saveNote(props.autht, row.key, row.request, row.pub_date, row.comments); //this function calls PUT REST API to save to the DB
   setData(newData);   //function from useState to ensure the element is re-rendered
};
```

What should be done to make the pk available in the DatePicker callback?
Or perhaps the approach should be change some variable that would trigger the updating of the whole Table row. Cannot quite my head around it.
Is it at all possible, or should i accept Antd DatePicker does not fit here?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can do something like this `<DatePicker onOk={(date)=> saveDateToDB(date, ...key... ) }/>`.

Answer (score 0):

So, the way it could be done: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-architecture-g64rmy?file=/src/App.js)

The columns array can be initialized using the 'record' object, the 'key' being its attribute.

```js
const initColumns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      width: "25%",
      editable: true
    },
    {
      title: "From Date",
      dataIndex: "pub_date",
      width: "25%",
      render: (_, record) =>
        reqdata.length >= 1 ? (
          <div ref={ref} id={record.key}>
            <DatePicker
              className={record.key}
              format="YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss"
              onChange={onChange}
              onOk={(date) => {
                onOk(date);
                console.log(`key: ${record.key}`);
              }}
              showTime
            />
          </div>
        ) : null
    }
  ];
```

i still did not figure out how to pass the record.key as a parameter to onOk(), but the goal seems to be achieved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).